# SessionSet Json Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a table which contains an "edit" button.

I created a function that gets the json data and returns it to my table. This is done before anything else. Once the data is returned, i want to make a column in my table with edit buttons redirect a user when "edit" is clicked to a form which outputs based on the user id.

So far, my json call looks like:

```
  var Json_return = [];
  jQuery(function(){
    jQuery.getJSON('showmydata.php',{},function(data){
        Json_return = data;
        console.log (data);
        jQuery(Json_return).each(function(indx,Val){
        jQuery('[name="dataTable"]').eq(0).append
                  ('<tr class="rowstart"><td class="sourceid"
                    align="center">'+Val.ID+'</td><td class="assignto"
                    align="center">'+Val.Preparedby+'</td><td class="dateprep
                    editable_textarea" align="center">'+Val.DatePrepared+'</td>
                    <td class="followup editable_textarea"
                    align="center">'+Val.FollowUpDate+'</td>
                    <td class="emer editable_textarea"
                    align="center">'+Val.Emergency+'</td>
                    <td class="edit" align="center">
                    <button id="edit" class="tiny radius" 
                    data-ID="'+Val.ID+'">Edit</button></td></tr>'); 
        });
    });
});
```

Which spits out a nicely formatted table by appending my table rows to deliver my data accordingly.

What I can't figure out is how to set the value from my json into my localStorage. My script looks like this:

```
<script>
$("button#edit).click(function(){
    localStorage.setItem("recordID", '+Val.ID+');
});
</script>
```

Any ideas or segway into finding the address would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try `localStorage.setItem("recordID", Val.ID)`?

Comment: The answer below is a great one. However, you may get into issues due to CAPS in data attributes. Therefore change everything in your markup and code to lowercase data attributes e.g. `data-ID` --> `data-id`. @ProstoTrader

Comment: @user3558931 i switched to lowercase for date-id...thanks for the tip. ill keep it in mind next time i use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read attribute data-ID of the button, since it's there:

```
$("button#edit").click(function(){
    localStorage.setItem("recordID", $(this).attr('data-ID'));
});
```

Comment: Gave it a try but nothing is happening. I did change data-id param to all lowercase as well in my attr tag. Still nothing. Hmmm...

Comment: after going back and moving my click function further up in my json request...it worked like a charm and is now storing my ID in localStorage...THANKSSSSSSS A MILLION!!!! it worked...